# SQLite Multiple Column Primary Key Constraint

Tags: sqlite, primary-key, multiple-columns, clustered-index, rsqlite

I am working in a SQLite db with a few billion rows.  It is a archival db with very few writes.  My main interest is to generate a cluster index of the data.  Working through RSQLite interface, I am able to generate a table and standard index as follows.

```
    dbSendStatement(SQLiteConn, "CREATE TABLE VSReports (ReportId bigint Not Null, EvtDateTime text, ConditionCode text, Basis text, ConditionLabel text, VitalSignCode text, VitalSignLbl text, VSUnit text, VSValue text);")
```

A patient report is submitted and entered once, it will have multiple observations by time,  each observation will report a condition code, its nomeclature and its basis, finally each condition will have a vital sign, its nomenclature, unit of measure and value.
To the best of my understanding, each entry is uniquely identified via
ReportId, EvtDateTime, ConditionCode, Basis, VitalSignCode
Additionally, I would like my data to be written as the following cluster.
ConditionCode, VitalSignCode, ReportId, EventDateTime, Basis

There for I created another database and  table (doing this for disk space constraint, could make table in same db)

```
        dbSendStatement(SQLiteConn2, "CREATE TABLE VSReports (ReportId bigint Not Null, EvtDateTime text, ConditionCode text, Basis text, ConditionLabel text, VitalSignCode text, VitalSignLbl text, VSUnit text, VSValue text, PRIMARY KEY (ConditionCode, VitalSignCode, ReportId, EvtDateTime, Basis));")
```

I am currently running a select query against the database

```
dbGetQuery(SQLiteConn, "SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT MIN(ROWID) as Keep, MAX(ROWID) as Rmove, COUNT(ROWID) as Fltr 
        FROM VSReports
        GROUP BY  ConditionCode, VitalSignCode, ReportId, EventDateTime, Basis) as InnerQ
    WHERE Fltr >1
    Limit 1;")
```

So far this has generated no return.  Will likely take a day or two to complete.
However when I try to populate the Primary Key table with the old one it errors immediately.

```
dbSendStatement(SQLiteConn2, "ATTACH DATABASE 'C:/Temp/Old.db' as Priordb;"
dbSendStatment(SQLiteConn2, "INSERT INTO VSReports SELECT * FROM Priordb;"
```

I recieve a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT failed.
However, if I modicy the table as

```
           dbSendStatement(SQLiteConn2, "CREATE TABLE VSReports (ReportId bigint Not Null, EvtDateTime text, ConditionCode text, Basis text, ConditionLabel text, VitalSignCode text, VitalSignLbl text, VSUnit text, VSValue text , UnqId as bigint, PRIMARY KEY (ConditionCode, VitalSignCode, ReportId, EvtDateTime, Basis, UnqId ));")
```

Then

```
dbSendStatment(SQLiteConn2, "INSERT INTO VSReports SELECT * , ROWID AS UnqId  FROM Priordb;")
```

Then the data transfer  initiates.
Obviously ROWID  in Priordb carries a UNIQUE constraint.
However, I thought the purpose of a multi-column PRIMARY KEY was that the combination of values would generate an unique identifier.

1. The primary goal is the on disk cluster partitioning of the data so if I have to add this dummy feature at the end I will. however, this invovles at least two data table populations.  However, I would prefer not to have it.
2. Can I compose this PRIMARY KEY without the specifically UNIQUE element?
3. Can I gnerate this UNIQUE element dynamically so to skip the initial population of a DB to get a ROWID?

Comment: A *constraint* just restricts what you can enter into the table. In SQLite, [autoincrementing](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) works only with a one-column PK.

Comment: SO I understood that the AUTOINCREMENT keyword really just slightly different ROWID selection algorithm is used.
[link](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).  Any interger primary key autoincrement becomes an alias for the ROWID.  
I thought a Primary Key was a type of constraint
[link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_constraints.htm).  In this case am building a composite key. 
If a table has a primary key defined on any field(s), then you cannot have two records having the same value of that field(s).  I believe that without the ROWID from a prior build I meet this requirement.

Comment: A clustered index table requires [WITHOUT ROWID](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html). However, I still do not understand what the actual problem is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks, I had overlooked the WITHOUT ROWID.  Unfortunately, the GROUP BY query returned duplications within what I was told was a unique identifier.  Seems that SQLite was performing correctly.  I guess the problem boiled down to an expectation of my Limit 1 to find the match as fast as my INSERT command errored.    There appear to be no guaranteed UNIQUE column combination nor a way to add a UNIQUE value at the end (AUTOINCREMENT) to create a clustered index of this data.
However, if there is a method to add some UNIQUE element at the end that would be great.